# (Proof Verification) the set of all closed bounded intervals has cardinality c

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

Here is my proof for the statement that the set of all closed bounded intervals has cardinality $c.$

Let $S$ denote the set of all closed bounded intervals.

We know that any element in $S$ is of the form $[a,b]$ where $a,b \in \Bbb R.$ Define the function $f$ from the set $S$ to $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ by sending $[a,b]$ to $(a,b).$

This is obviously a bijection. Since $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ has cardinality $c$, we are done.

Can someone have a look at my proof? I am concerning that $f$ may not be a function. Is $f$ really a function?

Comment: It is not a bijection becasue $(1,0)$ is not in the image. But at least $f$ is a function because for the given (non-empty) closed bounded interval $I$, the numbers $a:=\inf I$ and $b:=\sup I$ are well-defined. You need to verify that this function is injective. As it is not surjective, you may want to exhibit another (injective) function $\Bbb R\to S$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh. Then there is a problem because what I am considering is the set of all closed bounded intervals, which includes the empty set (e.g. $[4,3]=\emptyset$.) In this case, $f$ is not a function because the empty set is sent to more than one elements like $(4,3),(5,3),(6,3)...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well almost.

What you need for an interval $[a,b]$ is not only that $a,b\in \mathbb R$, but also that $a\le b$, that is $S=\{[a,b]: a\le b\}$. Your solution has issues because of that. However that can be fixed.

If we can use Cantor-Bernstein (that is $|A|\le |B|$ and $|B|\le |A$ implies that $|A|=|B|$) we could fix this note that the finite intervals have an bijection to a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ (or that it is a injection), so we know that $|S||\le |\mathbb R^2|=|\mathbb R|$. We also have an surjection (fx $f([a,b])=a$) to $\mathbb R$ so we know that $|S|\ge|\mathbb R|$. Now Cantor-Bernstein shows that $|S|=|\mathbb R|$

If you can't use Cantor-Bernstein you would map the subset of $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ bijectively. What we basically need is a bijection $\phi$ that maps $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$ to $\mathbb R$. With that we can form the bijection by mapping $[a,b]$ to $(a, \phi(b-a))$. The only thing is to construct such a bijection $\phi$. This can be done by noting that we can uniquely decompose any number $x = n(x)+\xi(x)$ where $n(x)$ is an integer (which is non-negative if $x$ is) and $0\le \xi(x)<1$. So we define $\phi$ as

$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
n(x)/2 + \xi(x) & \text{ if } n(x) \text { is even}\\
-(n(x)+1)/2 +\xi(x)  & \text{ if } n(x) \text { is odd}
\end{cases}$$

Basically we map the integer part using a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: What I need to prove is the statement that "the set of all closed bounded interval has cardinality $c$". Although $[-\infty, b]$ is a closed interval, it is not a closed **bounded** interval. But here is a problem: $[4,3]$ is a closed bounded interval because the empty set is bounded. That means the $f$ defined in my proof is not actually a function, as I explained to @HagenvonEitzen.

Comment: @PropositionX That one is solved by disallowing $[4,3]$ as an interval. You only include intervals like $[a,b]$ where $a\le b$ in $S$, thereby the map to $\mathbb R^2$ will be a proper function, but it will only be an injection showing that $|S|\le|\mathbb R^2|$. The inclusion of infinite intervals can be omitted if you want - see it as a bonus that infinite interval does not increase the cardinality.

Comment: Thanks so much. May I please ask how to find an explicit injection from $\Bbb R^2$ to $S$?

Comment: I have seen your edited answer. Thanks so much.